# If/Else statement doesn't work properly in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm a newbie programmer and I had a problem with if/else statement in my code. the first and the second conditions work pretty well, but the last `else`, which is supposed to return the main input (the entered `n`) without any change, returns incorrect answer. Where is the problem? The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n > 3000000) {
        n = n * 0.9;
        cout << n;
    }
    else if (2000000 < n < 3000000) {
        n = n * 0.95;
        n = n * 0.97;
        cout << n;
    }
    else {
        cout << n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For god's sake use code formatting!

Comment: You can't do "2000000<n<3000000".  You need to break it up into two conditionals.  ((2000000 < n) && (n < 3000000)).  Also, the block of the else if can be broken down to n *= .97 * .95;.

Comment: `2000000<n<3000000)` does not do what you think it does. You should learn to a) properly format and indent your code so it's readable, and b) learn to use a debugger to step through the code to see what it does and how it works.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); then **use the debugger** `gdb`  to run  your program step by step and understand what is going on.

Comment: thank you so much JGroven;) it helped

Comment: PROTIP: C++ lets you type spaces. Having spaces between stuff increases humans' chances of being able to read it without having to take an inordinate amount of time squinting at it and figuring out where one token ends and the next begins.

Answer (score 0):

mistake in condition defining:  `( (n>2000000) && (n<3000000) )`